# Scrapy problems with crawling specific TAG

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having a problem with my scrapy program, I want to crawl information from following website
[https://parts.cat.com/AjaxCATPartLookupResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&requestType=1&storeId=21801&serialNumber=KSN00190&keyword=&link=>](https://parts.cat.com/AjaxCATPartLookupResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&requestType=1&storeId=21801&serialNumber=KSN00190&keyword=&link=%3E)
I want to get the "Part No." information inside the "span id=resPartNum" TAG. I have already tried:

```
- NAME_SELECTOR = './/*[@id="resPartNum"]/text()'
- NAME_SELECTOR = './/span[@class="resPartNum"]/text()
- NAME_SELECTOR = './/tr/td/span[@class="resPartNum"]/a/text()'
```

Here is my full CODE:

```
import scrapy

class PartSpider(scrapy.Spider):  
   name = 'part_spider'  
   start_urls = ['https://parts.cat.com/AjaxCATPartLookupResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&requestType=1&storeId=21801&serialNumber=KSN00190&keyword=&link=']  

   def parse(self, response):  
       SET_SELECTOR = '.set'  
       for part in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

           NAME_SELECTOR = './/*[@id="resPartNum"]/text()'

           yield {
               'name': part.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
           }
```

I am not very advanced in scrapy and would appreciate ANY HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the css selector `table.partlookup_table` to collect the table item  through loop partNum and partName.here extract() return list.

```
import scrapy

class PartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'part_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://parts.cat.com/AjaxCATPartLookupResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&requestType=1&storeId=21801&serialNumber=KSN00190&keyword=&link=']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = 'table.partlookup_table'
        for part in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

               #NAME_SELECTOR = './/*[@id="resPartNum"]/text()'

               yield {
                   'name': part.css('span.resPartName  a::text').extract(),
                   'partnumber': part.css('span.resPartNum a::text').extract()
               }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(PartSpider)

process.start()
```

Comment: Sorry for another question, but I want to put the extracted data "name" and "partnumber" into a list, but can't use 'name' and 'partnumber' inside the yield function as list item. Further help would AWESOME! I want to have something like this:

yield{
                'name' : part.css('span.resPartName a::text').extract(),
                'partnumber' : part.css('span.resPartNum a::text').extract()
            }
data = (name, partnumber)

Comment: create a list then put item in it. here a function:                                                                                          def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = 'table.partlookup_table'
        data = []
        for part in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            name= part.css('span.resPartName  a::text').extract()
            data.append(name)
            partnumber= part.css('span.resPartNum a::text').extract()
            data.append(partnumber)
            print(data)